# I need to return a column using two tables as reference

Tags: mysql

hi i need some help i need  my query to return a values that is not found in a **table A** using the values on **table B** as a reference.

### table A

```
column_id 
--
1
2
3
4
```

then

### table B

```
column_number
--
1
4
```

and it should return a column like this

```
returned_column
--
2
3
```

anyhelp will be great.

Comment: i mean  i need my query to return a values that is found in a table B using the values from table A as a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select table1.column_number 
from table1 
left join table2 on table1.column_number  =table2.column_number 
where table2.column_number  is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT column_id AS returned_column
FROM tableA
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tableB
                  WHERE tableB.column_number = tableA.column_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `left join` also

```
select 
    table_A.column_id as returned_column
from
    table_A
        left join
    table_B ON table_A.column_id = table_B.column_number
where
    table_B.column_number is null
```